# AngularJS ng-init is not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I need a Sum of Balance from the Following Data in HTML not in JS Controller Function. So, I used the **ng-init** within the **ng-repeat**. But I can't able to get the result.

My JSON Data is

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "ldat":"2014-08-13",
         "eid":"HSL018",
         "dr":"55420",
         "cr":"0",
         "bal":"55420"
      },
      {
         "ldat":"2014-10-11",
         "eid":"HBL056",
         "dr":"0",
         "cr":"35000",
         "bal":"20420"
      },
      {
         "ldat":"2014-10-26",
         "eid":"HBL001",
         "dr":"0",
         "cr":"420",
         "bal":"20000"
      },
      {
         "ldat":"2015-11-01",
         "eid":"HDL001",
         "dr":"0",
         "cr":"20000",
         "bal":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

My HTML is

```
<h3>Net Balance {{ legTot }}</h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">#</td>
      <td class="text-center">Last Trans</td>
      <td class="text-center">Dr</td>
      <td class="text-center">Cr</td>
      <td class="text-center">Balance</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy:'eid' | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
      <td>{{ $index + 1 | number }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ x.ldat }}</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{ x.dr | currency:"&#8377;" }}</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{ x.cr | currency:"&#8377;" }}</td>
      <td class="text-right" ng-init="legTot = legTot + x.bal | number">{{ x.bal | currency:"&#8377;" }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I used the  `ng-init="legTot = legTot + x.bal | number"` to sum the balance `legTot` is a Scope Variable.

I Can't able to get the total. Kindly assist me how to achieve this without foreach loop in AngularJS Controller Function.

Comment: I believe `ng-init` should be on the same element as `ng-repeat`

Comment: There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`, such as for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.

Comment: you aren't accounting for child scopes created by ng-repeat. This needs to be done in controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-init creates new child scope. To inherit scope variables from parent to child, you should put those variable to an object. In your scope in controller, create object with name 'vm' and put your 'legTot' variable inside it.

```
$scope.vm = {legTot: 0}
```

And change html

```
<h3>Net Balance {{ vm.legTot }}</h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">#</td>
      <td class="text-center">Last Trans</td>
      <td class="text-center">Dr</td>
      <td class="text-center">Cr</td>
      <td class="text-center">Balance</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy:'eid' | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
      <td>{{ $index + 1 | number }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ x.ldat }}</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{ x.dr | currency:"&#8377;" }}</td>
      <td class="text-right">{{ x.cr | currency:"&#8377;" }}</td>
      <td class="text-right" ng-init="vm.legTot = vm.legTot + Number(x.bal)">{{ x.bal | currency:"&#8377;" }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It Showing the Net Balance 05542020420200000. It considers the number as a sting, so it concatenates the number. Kindly check it once...

Comment: Because x.bal is string. I have edited the code. ng-init="vm.legTot = vm.legTot + Number(x.bal)" should work. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution without `forEach` loop [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/td9cawfd/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.legTot = 0;
  $scope.addBal = function(bal){
    $scope.legTot+=bal;
  }
  $scope.data = [{
    "ldat": "2014-08-13",
    "eid": "HSL018",
    "dr": "55420",
    "cr": "0",
    "bal": "55420"
  }, {
    "ldat": "2014-10-11",
    "eid": "HBL056",
    "dr": "0",
    "cr": "35000",
    "bal": "20420"
  }, {
    "ldat": "2014-10-26",
    "eid": "HBL001",
    "dr": "0",
    "cr": "420",
    "bal": "20000"
  }, {
    "ldat": "2015-11-01",
    "eid": "HDL001",
    "dr": "0",
    "cr": "20000",
    "bal": "0"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h3>Net Balance {{ legTot }}</h3>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">#</td>
        <td class="text-center">Last Trans</td>
        <td class="text-center">Dr</td>
        <td class="text-center">Cr</td>
        <td class="text-center">Balance</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in data track by $index">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 | number }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ x.ldat}}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ x.dr  }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ x.cr }}</td>
        <td class="text-right" ng-init="addBal(x.bal*1)">{{ x.bal }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Let I know why you are multiplying the x.bal with 1 ?

Comment: In html template you are using  filter `number` (`legTot = legTot + x.bal | number`). Because i'm adding value in JS, then simplest way convert **string** to **number** is multiply buy 1.